# Clearing the buffer when using Getchar (there must be a better way!)

Tags: c, char, getchar, fflush

I am writing a function where I only need to obtain a single digit, I decided to use getchar() instead of scanf().

However since I only need one character I did not use an array to obtain it. This causes a problem because I dont have a loop to find the '/n' character. To make sure my buffer is cleared before using getchar() again, I wrote this:

```
while (getchar() != '\n'){}
```

It works as I need it to, but is this the "correct" way to go about this problem?

I tried using fflush(stdin), but it seems to not have any effect.

Thank you for all replies, I check the comments often and would love to answer questions.

Comment: The `while` runs into a non-terminating loop when there's no newline (e.g. on End Of File).

Comment: @Jens There is no  infinite loop if getchar was successful.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow And how do you know it will be successful?

Comment: @Jens By checking the value returned by the call of getchar.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Right; and here it is only checked for being a newline. Can you see how this can be a non-terminating loop? Hint: what happens when stdin is "foobar<EOF>"?

Answer (score 3):

Note that `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior according to the C Standard, though it is supported by a few implementations.

The idiomatic way to do this is:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    continue;
}
```

The check for `EOF` is needed to avoid an infinite loop in the event that there is an error in `getchar()`, or if the user signals `EOF` from the keyboard. The variable `c` needs to be an `int` to ensure that it can hold the value of `EOF`, which is typically -1.

Also be aware that this method requires that there be at least one character left in the input stream, otherwise `getchar()` will block, waiting for input. A previous call to `getchar()` or `scanf()` will leave at least a newline behind, but calls to `fgets()` may not.